# Good high-gain amp chip

Tags: operational-amplifier

In a previous question, I asked about an audio-induction loop, and how I would amplify it. I am wondering what chip I should use to  drive a 8 ohm speaker and what the circuit would look like. I mentioned the tl082,(an op-amp I have a lot of) but that didn't seem to delver enough power. I want to power this with a 12 volt battery.

Comment: TL082 will drive an \$8\Omega\$ speaker just fine. It just may not be very loud. How big is the speaker? How much volume do you need?

Comment: I dont need much because i am going to put it on the input of another amp

Comment: do I need a negative voltage?

Comment: @skyler negative voltage? Not if you use the LM380 (see answer below)

Comment: If it's driving the input of another amp, then it's not driving an 8 ohm speaker; the question is misleading.

Comment: @skyler No, you do not need a negative supply if you are using a chip amp designed for **single-supply** use, such as the OPA549 in the answer below.

Comment: @Phil: No, a TL08x is really not good for driving a 8 Ohm load, at least at any power level required by something called a "speaker" in normal use.  I didn't see a max output current spec in the datasheet, but the equivalent circuit shows nearly 100 Ohms in series with the output, so it won't drive a 8 Ohm load very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LM380 is quite widely used: -

[image]

[image]

[Here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Flm380.pdf&ei=JvmtUZvaJMaVPOy0gKAP&usg=AFQjCNGWTOxDVE0rUybi3civZS2jp_GmPQ&sig2=IOctPXg6frSFWDakS0HaYA&bvm=bv.47244034,d.ZWU) is the data sheet

Comment: how much gain is the max on this

Comment: It's voltage gain is fixed at 50 - front page of specification.

Answer (score 1):

A high current, high power op amp designed to work with a split supply voltage `|V+| + |V-| = 12 Volts` or a single supply voltage of 12 Volts would meet the requirement.

Consider the Texas Instruments [OPA549](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa549.pdf) high voltage high current operational amplifier, which can drive a sustained output current of up to 8 Amperes continuously, and works with supply voltages from 8 Volts to 60 Volts.

Keep in mind that this part (and others like it) is useful primarily at audio frequencies: A low Gain-Bandwidth Product of just 900 KHz would constrain its use for frequencies far beyond the audible range.