# How can I modify this circuit for a higher gain?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, amplifier, gain

Here is an image of an amplifier circuit.

How can I modify this for a 10-50 times more gain. I put a wire from pin 1 to 8, but I didn't get enough gain.

[image]

Comment: Start with a data sheet -- http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf.  If you've place a capacitor without a resistor between pins 1 and 8, that's maximum gain of 200.

Comment: The LM386 gain can be varied from 20 to 200, a factor of 10.  What value of gain do you want?

Comment: I dont know exactly, but more than a wire across pin 8 and 1

Comment: Wow, that's the first time I've seen LM386 described as tube-like.

Comment: @markrages They are about the same age, aren't they? ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave pin 1 to 8 open. Add another gain stage ahead of the LM386.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRCjzq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This non inverting amplifier has a gain of \$A=1+\dfrac{R_f}{R_i}\$. Gain can be increased by increasing the value of the feedback resistor. Add the LM386 gain stage and total gain becomes \$A=20(1+\dfrac{R_f}{R_i})\$.

The voltage divider and capacitor add a DC bias to the the non-inverting pin. This will allow it run from a single supply, and acts as a 50 Hz high pass filter. Do not forget to add C2 as well. Without it, the amplifier will just slam the positive rail.

However, if this is for that induction loop you keep talking about, I doubt you will ever be able to get enough power out of an LM386.

Comment: will tl082 work?

Comment: The TL082 is just a 2 gate version of the TL081.

Comment: I don't have a good neg. voltage. Can I just split the 12v into 2 6 volt suplies somehow?

Comment: @skyler Make the changes I indicated on the schematic, and connect the power pins to 12V and ground.

Comment: Ok. So did you add some sort of high-pass filter?

Comment: C1 contains the DC to the the non-inverting pin. It forms a first order high pass filter with the R3 and R4 parallel combination.

Comment: would 2 4.7uf caps in series work to make 2.35? I can't seem to find a 2.2uf and I dont feel like biking to RadioShack

Comment: That would be fine.

Comment: nevermind I found one

Comment: I built the circuit, and it worked, so I tried to increase the gain, but changing the values of R1 and R2 didn't make a difference. In fact, it was the same (no audio differences)  just taking out R1, and C2, and removing ground there.

Comment: What did you change them to?

Comment: I changed the 100K to 1M and got nothing at all, so then I put a really low value in for the 100k (56ohms) and it did the same as with the 100k. Then, I tried 500k and it was the same as 100K. Then I took out c2 and r1, and it was the same. With the opamp preamp, the volume was quieter then without.

Comment: Is there a cap between the LM386 and op amp output?

Comment: yes, a .01 uf cap

Comment: I replaced the chip and rebuilt the circuit, and I still have the same reslults

Comment: I think I got it to work finally, but the sound quality decreased a lot when I gained it too much (even when I went really far away where there wasnt much audio) so I am just going to buy the lm380 from here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71608/good-high-gain-amp-chip do you think the circuit shown has enough gain?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9153/discussion-between-skyler-and-matt-young)

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to set the gain, which the datasheet briefly mentions but it doesn't go into any detail.

"Gain control can also be done by capacitively coupling  a resistor (or FET) from pin 1 to ground."

See:

http://www.wentztech.com/radio/resources/Technical-Info/_LM386/Unleash-lm386.pdf

which discusses how to use that method to get a gain of over 4500 (73dB).  It requires careful layout and grounding.