# Why is my audio amp picking up AM and FM radio stations?

Tags: amplifier, radio

I built an audio amp out of the LM386 on a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71646/how-can-i-modify-this-circuit-for-a-higher-gain). I when I have nothing connected, I picked up FM radio stations, as well as AM Very loud and clear. Why is this happening? Why AM and FM?

How can I prevent this? Although it is very cool that I picked up the stations, I don't want to have any interference.

I live in Evergreen, Colorado (just west of Denver), and I am picking up 105.1 FM as well as 850 KOA AM

Yes I am sure that the one is FM because I heard them say "KOOL 105!!!!"

Comment: How do you know these are AM and FM? Some radio station have both. A better indication would be frequency. Do you have tools to see what frequency you receive? Otherwise, see if you can find out the station and on which frequency / _frequencies_ it transmits.

Comment: It's picking up FM? Seriously? If so, then that's awesome.

Comment: Put a 20K to 100K resistor between your input and GND.  While not guaranteed to work, it might make a big difference.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me too, but in my case circuit was supposed to be AM receiver.

Comment: Basically, the amp has bad input filtering.  It doesn't get rid of RF like it's supposed to, so some of it gets thru.  However, the circuitry can't reall deal with RF, but some gets rectified and *that* gets amplied.  Try adding 1 kOhm resistor in series with preamp input followed by 4.7 nF to ground close to the amp.  That should kill RF before it gets in and causes trouble.

Comment: LOL! I just caved in and subscribed, for the first time, to a RSS feed off StackExchange: skyler!

Comment: I'd be amazed if you got any radio station in Evergreen.  Doubly so if it was on your amp thing.  Now stop starting fires.

Comment: Oh wow everybody knows about the fires!

Comment: Heh, @Ignacio.  I got it.  That would be a neat trick, all right.  +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Radio frequencies from AM stations get into audio amplifiers not only through the inputs, but also via the outputs.

The speaker cabling can serve as an antenna to pick up radio signals. This is is coupled back to the output of the amplifier. But the amplifier has a negative feedback loop which feeds the output back to the input. So the output is really just another input.

Production amplifiers usually include a [Boucherot Cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boucherot_cell) on the output, often an output inductor after that. Both of these devices can help block incoming RF, even though it's not their main function. The Boucherot cell is simply a capacitor in series with a resistor, placed between the output and ground. Common values are 0.1uF and 10 ohms.  You can see this in many amplifier schematics. *Edit:* I see there is a 10 ohm/0.047uF cell in the amplifier; did you install that in the built circuit?

When you say "nothing connected", of course you have the speaker connected, which is how you hear the radio stations!

There is also the possibility that the circuit itself is picking up interference. There is a reason why amplifiers are built built into metal boxes and why fuss is made over any internal wiring and in particular grounding! If your power amp is just bare components on a breadboard, don't be surprised if it is susceptible. Radio waves are falling on your nest of wires and components. You have high gain in your circuit, and nonlinearities, so these oscillations are amplified and rectified.

There is also the power supply connection. A single-supply amplifier like the LM386 is very susceptible to noise coming in over the power supply. You have to bypass the power supply very well. A single large capacitor may not be enough; you need a small 0.1 uF ceramic close to the IC power pins.

Comment: I once had lots of trouble getting good modem connections, but heard weird sounds out the modem speaker.  One day I happened to pick up the phone just as the modem was dropping carrier, and heard what sounded like a radio broadcast.  I sent an `ATH1` to the modem and determined that whenever my modem was off-hook, some combination of the computer, phone line, and modem would pick up a radio station.  What I never did figure out was why the problem exhibited itself with both my internal modem and my external one, and why disconnecting the computer from...

Comment: ...the external modem while both it and a phone were off-hook (via ATH1) would cause the radio audio to go away.  Weird.

Comment: I would tend to say that the problem pointed toward the computer.

Comment: That was my thinking, but in retrospect it might have been interesting to take the computer elsewhere and see what it did with some other phone line.  My next computer worked fine with that phone line, but I can't imagine any problem that was "just" in the computer could have gone through the isolation barrier in the modem.  I've encountered had a number of objects which have long since been junked, that I sometimes wish I still had so I could find out how they could have possibly had the problems they did.  Another weird one [unrelated] was...

Comment: ...a fluorescent light that, if unplugged while switched on, would sit with 180+ volts DC potential on the plug (higher than peak mains voltage!).  Shorting the plug terminals would cause the light to flash briefly as its internal capacitance (I think the biggest cap was 100uF or so) discharged.  Not sure what the circuit was supposed to be or what it was.  Outside of the annoying zappy behavior the light worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

An FM signal will Amplitude Modulate a tuned circuit. A non-linear circuit will do peak-detection on an AM signal. An Audio Amplifier will amplify small signals detected by peak-detection of AM signals.

You prevent that by adding low-pass capacitor-resistor filters to your inputs, and high-pass filters to negative feedback paths.