# Why is my guitar amplifier acting like a radio when I touch the volume knob?

Tags: amplifier, rf

I just bought an acoustic/electric mandolin (Ibanez M511SE-DVS) that I decided to test out with the only guitar amp that I have (a Baja BG-10). It works fine, but I noticed that when I have my finger on the volume knob, I receive (what is most likely) an FM signal to a local radio station.

Given that I don't have a background in electrical engineering, in layman's terms what are the reasons that a guitar amplifier would pick up a radio signal and feed it back through the output (speaker)? This behavior only happens when I touch the *volume* button.

Comment: Your body acts as an aerial. Replace the volume knob with a plastic one, and repeat the experiment :D

Comment: See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71727/why-is-my-audio-amp-picking-up-am-and-fm-radio-stations?rq=1

Comment: @pjc50 I've already read that question, but there is a primary difference between mine and theirs - I only pick up radio signals when I *touch* the device, specifically the volume knob. I know from that question that it's receiving radio waves arbitrarily, but why they feed back when I touch a specific knob is what I'm interested in. I edited the title and question body to make this more clear.

Comment: When you touch it, the antenna becomes large enough to receive the signal clearly enough for it to be discernible/audible.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I figured that out, but why my body acts as an extention is what I'm questioning :)

Comment: Because the LRC tank created is resonant at the signal's carrier frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitance from the volume control knob through the pot is large enough to allow RF to couple through - from your body, when you touch the knob -  to the volume control circuitry, where it gets rectified/detected (turned into an audio signal) and sent through the rest of the amp to the loudspeaker.